# PassportJS (Google OpenID) nothing in req.user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

According to the [PassportJS docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/)

> If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the `req.user` property will be set to the authenticated user

However I had this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return",
    realm: "http://localhost:3000/"
}, function(id, profile, done) {
    console.log("Done: ", profile);
    done(null, profile);
}));

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {session: false}));
app.get('/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/failure',
    session: false
}));

app.get('/success', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.user));
});

app.get('/failure', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("FAIL");
});
```

And `req.user` in the route `/success` is `undefined`. The `req.user` in the `GoogleStrategy` definition is ok tho. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using sessions?

Try using this without {session: false}

```
app.use(express.cookieSession());
//passport config here
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//routes here
```

Comment: I was trying to create a RESTful API which is supposed to be stateless.

Answer (score 0):

`req.user` will not get set if you specify `session: false` in the options of your call to `passport.authenticate`.

You could use the user's profile as you are doing in the callback from the new GoogleStrategy, but be aware that your server might end up making the user authenticate each request instead of reusing the access token.